# Problem when i try to upgrade com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite. to newest version

Tags: android, react-native

I get a notification when I submit an app to google play, As of 00:00 on July 19, 2023 (UTC time zone), you will not be able to release a new version containing this SDK version. com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:19.8.0

I tried to change com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:19.8.0 to com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:22.0.0 in app/build.gradle but I got this error when building an app:

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0.
> Required by:
> project:app
> > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads' that satisfies the version constraints:
> Dependency path 'gostream:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0'
> Constraint path 'gostream:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:{strictly 19.8.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 19.8.0

> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:{strictly 19.8.0}.
> Required by:
> project : app
> > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads' that satisfies the version constraints:
> Dependency path 'gostream:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0'
> Constraint path 'gostream:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:{strictly 19.8.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 19.8.0

```
ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
    // googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.0.2"
    firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0" 
    googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "19.2.0"
    
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31
    androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"
    androidXBrowser = "1.0.0"
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle:4.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```